# adding back button using angular js bootstrap

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have to pages. first page I have bootstrap tab. please check below sample

1.first page is user page. its url `http://localhost:8081/#!/app/user`

in this page there is a tab controller.

```
       <div class="nav-tabs-custom">
                        <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                            <li class="active"><a href="#tab_1" target="_self" data-toggle="tab">One </a></li>
                            <li><a href="#tab_2" data-toggle="tab" target="_self">Two</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
         <div class="tab-content">
        <div class="tab-pane active" id="tab_1">
        content 01
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane" id="tab_2">
  content 02 
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
```

2. this is second page. its url `http://localhost:8081/#!/app/user-list`
   this page has back button. When user click this button, page should redirect to the first page (user page)  SECOND TAB. How i active SECOND TAB after redirect. Currently i am using below function

   $scope.goBack = function () {
   $state.go('app.user/#tab_2');
   }

Above back function is not working. how i do this work. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `$ionicHistory`?

```
// include $ionicHistory in your injected dependencies...

$scope.goBack = function() {
    $ionicHistory.goBack();
  };
```